# How to Solve the Mirror Modifier Error In Blender 2.82?

Tags: mirror

How to Solve the Mirror Modifier Error In Blender 2.82 ?

Hi guys I am now making the Zeta Gundam and I was creating a left leg of it.I was planning to make right leg with *mirror modifier*.So I moved *all of origins* in left leg into *the cursor* that's place at *world origin* to make sure that if i add mirror modifier, it will flip to became a right leg. But it doesn't work as I think. It only flip the foot to the right place but the rest parts of leg are flip into unusual sides. I changed the X,Y,Z in modifier but still doesn't work.As you can see in image,

*leg* flipped to top.

*thigh* and *knee joint* flipped to aside but

only *foot* flipped into right place.

Any idea or suggest to filp normally? Thank for the answer. [image]

Comment: Rotations are wrong for mirror along x, check your object rotations, clear them or apply them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to apply rotation, your rotations are wrong.

Comment: thanks guys I have solved the problem by apply rotation. thanks for the comments.